# SAP HANA user locked with too many invalid connect attempts

Tags: hana

I met one issue about user been locked by too many invalid connect attempts. After I used SYSTEM user to reactive this user and change the password in HANA studio, just few minutes later, the user would be locked with same reason even I did not do any operation on system. I totally got lost how it could happened.

Also I checked in my HANA studio. Whatever I did by using this user, it will trigger two lines of invalid connect attempts in system table INVALID_CONNECT_ATTEMPTS.

[image: INVALID_CONNECT_ATTEMPTS table]

Thanks in ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, because someone else maintain this user in other place and try to use old password to visit the system. That's the reason about the issue.